# Conditionally sum list

Tags: python, list, sum, conditional-statements

I have list like this:

```
[['a', '4'], ['b', '3'], ['d', '2'], ['a', '7'], ['c', '3.5'], ['a', '4'], ['d', '4'], ['b', '5'], ['eee', '4']]
```

I want to sum values for a,b,etc. so I want to have something like this:

```
a 15
b 8
c 3.5
d 6
eee 4
```

Another problem is my column with numbers has type string, so before suming  values I have to change type to float.
I can not use pandas `:(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [['a', '4'], ['b', '3'], ['d', '2'], ['a', '7'], ['c', '3.5'], ['a', '4'], ['d', '4'], ['b', '5'], ['eee', '4']]
>>> {k: sum(float(x) for _, x in v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(l), lambda x: x[0])}
{'a': 15.0, 'b': 8.0, 'c': 3.5, 'd': 6.0, 'eee': 4.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to save some boilerplate code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(float)

for k, v in data:
    d[k] += float(v)

for k in d:
    print(k, d[k])

a 15.0
b 8.0
d 6.0
c 3.5
eee 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
lst = [['a', '4'], ['b', '3'], ['d', '2'], ['a', '7'], ['c', '3.5'], ['a', '4'], ['d', '4'], ['b', '5'], ['eee', '4']]
res = {}
for i in lst:
    if i[0]  in res.keys():
        res[i[0]]  += float(i[1])
        continue
    res[i[0]]  = float(i[1])
print(res.items())
```